# How do I find the specific amount/frequency of positive, negative, and zero integers in a file? (Perl)

Tags: perl, file, input, integer, frequency

I am trying to open a file, scan it, and have the program print out the number of positive, negative, and zeroes.  I have the program successfully opening files, but finding the "Frequency" is what is giving me trouble.  I was ill the day of class and can't seem to find help pertaining to my specific prompt.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ( $ctrZ ) = ( 0 );
while( my $num = <DATA> ) {
        chomp($num);
        ## print "num=[$num]\n";
        if ( $num =~ /^-\d+$/ ) {
                $ctrZ++;
        }

printf("freq(0):%9s\n", $ctrZ );

exit;
__DATA__
19
-22
498
512
15
-932
0
22
808
17
-32
```

Note: Our professor gave us a file to use.  It is a .txt file with a single number on each line.

Comment: Do you really need comments like `chomp ($infile); #Chomps the $infile Variable.`?

Comment: yes our professor prefers us to have those.  Also, I added the wrong code to start with.  This is what I have.  I just need to find how many 0 integers are within the file.

Answer (score 1):

There's couple of problems with your code, but the major one is this:

```
if ($infile) { 
        $Pos_Int++;
        $Neg_Int++;
        $Zer_Int++;
}
```

That's only evaluating the content of `$infile` which is the filename. It will always be true, and therefore you'll always increment all your counters by one.

So all you're doing here is basically counting lines.

I would also suggest though, that you don't need to:

```
open(FHIN, '<', $infile); #Opens the file prompted by user. 
my @lines = <FHIN>; #Variable storing the number of lines in the file.
chomp( @lines ); 
close(FHIN);
```

Open a file, read it into an array, then iterate the array?

Why not instead go line by line with a while loop (it uses less memory, too).

Also - good style is to use lexical file handles rather than an upper case name, which is global scope.

So:

```
open ( my $input, '<', $infile ) or die $!;  #check return code for errors. 
while ( my $line = <$input> ) { #iterate the input line by line, setting $_ for each. 
    $Pos_Int++ if $line > 0;
    $Neg_Int++ if $line < 0;
    $Zer_Int++ if $line == 0; 
}
```

Should do the trick - but bear in mind it doesn't do any input validation. Regular expressions could help there, if it was necessary.

Also:

```
if (-e $infile) { #If the file can't be found, it will exit.

    } else {
        print ("No such file exists. Program closing.\n");
            exit;
}
```

This is redundant, because you can - and should - trap the return code from `open`. If you do that, then you catch other conditions like the file not being readable, or being a broken symbolic link or a bunch of other problems.

E.g.

```
open ( my $input, '<', $infile ) or die "Problem opening file: $!";
```

`$!` will give you an error code that's a bit more meaningful too - it'll tell you the difference between 'no such file or directory' and 'permission denied' for example.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the test for existence is superfluous, as the status of `open` must be checked anyway.

Comment: Just a note: *redundant* in American English can mean something more like *excessive*, *lavish*, or *beyond normal*. For instance two-factor authentication is "redundant" security. That's why I stick to *superfluous* in these pages.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `<=>` operator to get exactly what you want. According to [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators):

> Binary "`<=>`" returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on whether the left
>   argument is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than the right
>   argument.

So:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -wne '$count{$_ <=> 0}++; END { print Dumper(\%count); }' numbers.txt
```

Assuming *numbers.txt* contains the following:

```
111
0
-892
-664
21
0
63
868
-351
-263
467
-58
625
724
0
0
990
107
-739
-501
-386
909
-96
0
-735
```

Output will be:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '0' => 5,
          '1' => 10,
          '-1' => 10
        };
```